# Generate day-of-the-week objects from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, javascript-objects

I have an array of day ranges, like this:

`["Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun", ...]`

What I need is to create a large object which maps each one of these strings to an array containing all the relevant days, like this:

```
var object = {
  'Mon-Tue': ['Mon', 'Tue'],
  'Mon-Wed': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed'],
}
```

To help, I have an array of the possible days:

```
var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

Is this possible without doing it all manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far, and which part is giving you trouble? I would start by writing a routine that translates  "Mon-Fri" into a more useful pair of values (for example, 1 and 5).

Comment: What should be the output of `Fri-Tue`

Comment: @MaheerAli ['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for getting days with an index and iterate until you got all days.

```js
var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    daysMap = new Map(days.map((d, i) => [d, i])),
    data = ["Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(d => {
        var [start, end] = d.split('-'),
            temp = [],
            s = daysMap.get(start),
            e = daysMap.get(end);

        while (s !== e) {
            temp.push(days[s]);
            s++;
            s %= days.length
        }
        temp.push(days[s]);
        return { [d]: temp };
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like, you could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) for the wanted days.

```js
function* getDays(from, to) {
    var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        i = days.indexOf(from);

    while (days[i % days.length] !== to) yield days[i++ % days.length];
    yield days[i % days.length];
}

var data = ["Fri-Tue", "Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(d => ({ [d]: [...getDays(...d.split('-'))] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by using a tomorrow object, which gives the day of tomorrow.

```js
function* getDays(from, to) {
    var tomorrow = { Sun: 'Mon', Mon: 'Tue', Tue: 'Wed', Wed: 'Thu', Thu: 'Fri', Fri: 'Sat', Sat: 'Sun' };

    yield from;
    while (from !== to) yield from = tomorrow[from];
}

var data = ["Fri-Tue", "Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(d => ({ [d]: [...getDays(...d.split('-'))] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of `days`. First, `split` the range and get the indexes of current range.

- If `toIndex > fromIndex`, use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a portion of the array.
- If `fromIndex > toIndex`:

  - Get the array from `fromIndex` till the end of the `days` array
  - Plus, from 0 till `toIndex`

```js
const array = ["Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"]

const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

const output = {}

array.forEach(range => {
  const [fromIndex, toIndex] = range.split('-').map(a => days.indexOf(a))
  
  if(fromIndex > toIndex)
    output[range] = [...days.slice(fromIndex), ...days.slice(0, toIndex + 1)]
  else
    output[range] = days.slice(fromIndex, toIndex + 1)
})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like your answer. Your idea is too similar to my answer but I cant figure out what is three dots `...` in your code and how could it reduce my two lines in one line. If you could please leave an explanation in your answer it is much appreciated.

Comment: That's the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) introduced in ES6. Highly recommend going through the MDN page in the link. Here, I'm using it to [merge 2 arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays). It's similar to `concat`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps:

- Apply `reduce()` the array of strings containing ranges and set accumulator to empty object `{}`
- Then `split()` the string by `-`.
- Get the `indexOf()` each day inside the the `days` array.
- Then use `slice()` on `days` by providing it the indexes of first and second part of the string respectively.
- Set they string as new `key` and its value to array returned by `slice()`

```js
let arr =  ["Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"]

var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

let res = arr.reduce((ac,x) => {
  let temp = x.split('-').map(a => days.indexOf(a));
  ac[x] = days.slice(temp[0],temp[1]+1);
  return ac;
},{})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: 1. Not the same output. 2. Will not work for `Fri-Tue`

Comment: @Eddie Thanks for notifying I have edited. But I can't get second part. I mean what you expect `Fri-Tue` to return.

Comment: @MaheerAli Fri-Tue should return ['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'], so this doesn't quite work. +1 for simplicity though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let arr =  ["Mon-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"];
    var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
    
    var result = {};

    arr.map((x) => {

      var splitedArr = x.split('-');

      //left day < right day
      if (days.indexOf(splitedArr[0]) < days.indexOf(splitedArr[1]) + 1){
        var slicedDays = days.slice(days.indexOf(splitedArr[0]),days.indexOf(splitedArr[1]) + 1);
      }
      else{//left day > right day
        var slicedDays = days.slice(days.indexOf(splitedArr[0]),days.length);
        slicedDays = slicedDays.concat(days.slice(0,days.indexOf(splitedArr[1]) + 1));
      }

      result[x] = slicedDays;

    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to create an array with repeated days.

```js
let input = ["Fri-Tue", "Mon-Wed", "Mon-Thu", "Mon-Fri", "Mon-Sat", "Mon-Sun", "Tue-Mon", "Tue-Wed", "Tue-Thu", "Tue-Fri", "Tue-Sat", "Tue-Sun"];
let days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
let daysArr = [...days, ...days];

let out = {};

input.forEach((e) => {
 if(!out[e]) {
  out[e] = getDays(e);
 }
});

function getDays(str) {
 let [from, to] = str.split('-').map(e => days.indexOf(e));
 to = from < to ? to : to+7
 return daysArr.slice(from, to+1);
}

console.log(out)
```